# How do you specify which project to build from a multi-project solution in a github yml file?

Tags: yaml, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I recently connected my GitHub solution to my Azure AppService and it automatically created a yml build and deploy file which is great, thanks Microsoft. The issue is I have 4 projects in my solution but only want the Api deployed to the App service. How to I specify that?

```
build:
runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up .NET Core
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
    with:
      dotnet-version: '7.x'
      include-prerelease: true

  - name: Build with dotnet
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release

  - name: dotnet publish
    run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: .net-app
      path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

deploy:
runs-on: windows-latest
needs: build
environment:
  name: 'Production'
  url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

steps:
  - name: Download artifact from build job
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: .net-app

  - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
    id: deploy-to-webapp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: 'popupshop'
      slot-name: 'Production'
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.somesecret}}
      package: .
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error:

```
run: dotnet build ProjectFolder/Project.csproj --configuration Release

...

run: dotnet publish ProjectFolder/Project.csproj -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```